# Generate APK with files (json) in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusquest

I have a question about my project, to put it in context I have .json files in the Assets folder, although I think they should be in Resources. The thing is that when I test my project on the Oculus, reading the files works, but when I generate the apk and run the game, it no longer reads the files.

At first I thought that it changed the path inside the apk but when I unpacked the apk I didn't find the .json or if it was converted into another type of file. I am new to 3D and Unity I hope your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Unity will only compile things into your final build that are referenced, such as Textures being used in Materials, Scripts (`MonoBehaviours`) that are attached to `GameObjects` within scenes, etc.

Your hunch on using the `Resources` directory was correct. If you want to pass along files that aren't / can't be referenced by Unity, then you need to put these files into the `Assets/Resources` directory. Then you can read the files using the [`Resources.Load()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) method (or a different method in the `Resources` class).

The reason why it worked while testing using the Unity Editor, is because it doesn't simulate which resources do- and do not get passed onto your build, so it'll always use all the files that are in your project.

Edit: The [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity6.html) also recommends to use the `Addressables` package if your Resources directory gets too bloated, so you can also see the `Addressables` package as a potential solution to your problem.